# Adding music to the Play Music queue

Tags: google-play-music

In "play music" mode must I be using a play list for the 'add to queue' function to work?  Can I create an empty playlist with which to start queuing function? Add to queue does not seem to work when playing off the music library. Why?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to be using a play list to add stuff to the queue. As soon as you select music to play it adds it to the queue. To add more to the queue, navigate to an artist, album, playlist, or song and there should be an "add to queue" option in the overflow menu.